# Android Development Tools download no longer exist

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have been using standalone ADT with the green app. icon for a long time.

I started with a new company now and it's not the time now to start learning on the Android Studio. maybe I do that on a later stage.

The http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html page used to have the standalone ADT download. This is page now only include the Android Studio and it says The official Android IDE.

> Any idea how I can get the ADT download??

PS: I don't want to have it as an eclipse plugin.

Comment: [This](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other) says you don't need an IDE.

Comment: I need an IDE. no android developer do it without IDE.

Comment: well use Android Studio you will get a great tool and it's not in Beta anymore and it's realy stable

Comment: It's my first day in a new job and I already have deadlines. I don't have time to get used to the new tool.

Comment: So what tool is it that you want. Read the page I linked more carefully. It says you don't have to or you can use another one. Also, if you don't want the Eclipse plug-in why'd you tag your post with it?

Comment: Because ADT is an eclipse version. but, not the original one. also, I need the IDE download (ADT). not the sdk. don't worry about it.

Comment: @hasan83 means he want the `Android Bundle` the green icon { } ;) it was latest release of an IDE just before `Android Studio` became the official IDE

Comment: Oh @Yazan. hassan83, surely you know that "standalone" version was just Eclipse with the tools pre-installed with a fancy splash screen? ADT is a plugin *for Eclipse*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am not sure if this as latest build 
but try to download this, and update from SDK-Manager
i know how it feel on 1st day at new job, with unprepared Env.

[Download Windows](http://dl.google.com/android/adt/22.6.2/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321.zip)

[Download MAC](http://dl.google.com/android/adt/22.6.2/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321.zip)

good luck

Comment: I didn't mention that I want the Mac version :) Is this gonna give me the green beautiful icon :) ?

Comment: @hasan83 yes this is the beautiful Green icon, i have added MAC download too :)

Comment: how did you get those links?

Comment: @hasan83 i just searched the folder name in google, `adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321` and then i played a little with the result url, replacing linux with windows and mac ;)

Comment: @hasan83 yes but it's the original folder name when i downloaded it, nazzlo ya 7assan w shoof shoo feeh :D

Comment: It is downloading already man. waiting for result to accept your answer. sorry if you had the indication of those users who just talk non-sense.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been using standalone ADT with the green app. icon for a long
>   time.

This is actually a bundle of the ADT and Eclipse. From [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html) (emphasis mine)...

> ADT (Android Developer Tools) is ***a plugin for Eclipse*** that provides a
>   ***suite of tools that are integrated with the Eclipse IDE***. It offers you
>   access to many features that help you develop Android applications.
>   ADT provides GUI access to many of the command line SDK tools as well
>   as a UI design tool for rapid prototyping, designing, and building of
>   your application's user interface.

... so there's nothing "standalone" about ADT specifically. What may seem like a separate "standalone" ADT specific IDE is just an extended version of Eclipse; just like the [Spring Tool Suite](https://spring.io/tools). Surprising how confusing a splash-screen can be.

> The http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html page used to have the
>   standalone ADT download. This is page now only include the Android
>   Studio and it says The official Android IDE.

That's been an ongoing change for some time now. Android Studio isn't especially hard to use in comparison to Eclipse (the "standalone" ADT you speak of), but if the change doesn't concern you now you can still use the ADT in its form with a newer version of Eclipse.

I realize this isn't the version you speak of, but there's not much benefit in holding on to old tech. Due to Google's attitude toward AS, being that now they recommend you change instead of cautioning unseasoned users who prefer to be productive and not explorative, it's stable for production.

> Any idea how I can get the ADT download??

It's available in the link you provided, just not the way you're accustomed to it. This shouldn't matter since there's detailed instructions on how to get Eclipse and add the tools yourself. The problem is...

> PS: I don't want to have it as an eclipse plugin.

That's a logical impossibility. Because ADT is a plugin for Eclipse, as the Android Documents state, you'll have to have it as an Eclipse plugin; *that's what it is*. The question is do you want/need that fact abstracted from you so you can sleep at night; I suppose.

So the *best* answer, for a particular definition of best, would be to get an up-to-date version of Eclipse and then follow the [instructions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) on installing the ADT plugin. But it's worth noting that, as the docs say, to ensure you're up-to-date, you'll probably want to work on making the change.